# Inject font-display property to all @font-face

Tags: css, fonts

Chrome and other new browsers now allow `font-display: swap` to `@font-face`. This makes sure that font will be visible even before loading external font files

It's easy to modify local styles, However, there will be external styles like font-awesome that will download css files from their own domains

Is there any way to inject `font-display` to every `@font-face` vai css/js, like applying globally?

I found a script. But it's not guaranteed that it will be applied before the browser starts to apply it. So in effect, it doesn't work

```js
<script>
  [].slice.call(document.styleSheets).forEach(function(sheet) {
    [].slice.call(sheet.cssRules || []).forEach(function(rule) {
      if (rule.type === CSSRule.FONT_FACE_RULE)
        rule.style.fontDisplay = "swap";
    });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Instead, it's far more worth helping everyone on the internet by filing an issue for fontawesome (and all the others) requesting they add support for that feature?

Comment: It's not just font-awesome, it's an example. There are hundreds of other libraries which have the same issue

Comment: I doubt that, although it might def. be tens: still worth filing issues on all of them. (google and typekip are thousands of fonts that only need one issue filed each, for example)

Comment: Yes, there are already issues existing for them. But to get them fixed, released, updating plugins by developers in CMS will take time. I'm building a solution for wordpress so that everyone could benifit from it

Comment: As long as you understand that hacking up stylesheets is a short term fix that'll lead to long term bit rot. It is by far better to accept the current state of the web and roll with those punches, updating webfonts as their maintainers add support for font-display.

Comment: Yes, I know it's a short term fix. But it will help lots of sites util all these developers get this fixed!